# Why is my Android room database returning null?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

Im new to android in general, so I'm trying to access a pre-populated database with some user data but I keep getting null as an answer and I don't understand why. Here is the DAO:

```
@Dao
interface UserDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM User WHERE User.id = :id;")
    fun getUserById(id: Int): LiveData<User>
}
```

I get the data on the database definition and the instance creation. The data is in the assets/database:

```
@Database(entities = [User::class], version = 1)
abstract class MyAppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun userDao(): UserDao
    companion object {
        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE: MyAppDatabase? = null
        fun getDatabase(context: Context): MyAppDatabase =
            (INSTANCE ?:
            synchronized(this) {
                val i = INSTANCE ?: Room.databaseBuilder(
                    context.applicationContext,
                    MyAppDatabase::class.java,
                    "MobileApplicationsDatabase"
                )
                    .createFromAsset("database/MobileApplicationsDatabase.db")
                    .build()
                INSTANCE = i
                INSTANCE
            })!!
    }
}
```

Then, I use it in a ViewModel to keep track of the information:

```
class DBViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {
    private val userRepository: UserRepository
    private val _user = MutableLiveData<User>()
    var user: LiveData<User> = _user
    fun getUserById(id: Int): User?{
        _user.value = userRepository.getUserById(id).value
        return _user.value
    }
    init {
        val mydb = MyAppDatabase.getDatabase(application)
        val userDao = mydb.userDao()
        userRepository = UserRepository(userDao)
    }
}
```

Finally, I call it on the Main Activity during the onCreate like this:

```
var getNewUserButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button1)
val tv = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.mainTextView)
dbvm = ViewModelProvider(this).get(DBViewModel::class.java)
dbvm.user.observe(this){
     tv.text = "$it"
}
getNewUserButton.setOnClickListener {
     dbvm.getUserById(1)
}
```

So, If Im creating a database populated with data and calling a get when I press the button, why is nothing being shown?

Answer (score 1):

You're not observing the changes in LiveData properly - it is asynchronous, so you should avoid trying to get its value directly (using `userRepository.getUserById(id).value`) and instead, observe it and let it notify you when the data is available. Update  `DBViewModel` to expose the LiveData directly from the `UserRepository` and then observe it in the `MainActivity`.